# Share a file between two workflows in CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows, circleci-orb

In our repo `build` and `deploy` are two different workflows.

In `build` we call `lerna` to check for changed packages and save the output in a file saved to the current workspace.

```
  check_changes:
    working_directory: ~/project
    executor: node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project
      - run:
          command: npx lerna changed > changed.tmp
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ./
          paths:
            - changed.tmp
```

I'd like to pass the exact same file from `build` workflow to `deploy` workflow and access it in another job. How do I do that?

```
read_changes:
working_directory: ~/project
executor: node
steps:
  - checkout
  - attach_workspace:
      at: ~/project
  - run:
      command: |
        echo 'Reading changed.tmp file'
        cat changed.tmp
```

According to [this blog post](https://circleci.com/blog/persisting-data-in-workflows-when-to-use-caching-artifacts-and-workspaces/)

> Unlike caching, workspaces are not shared between runs as they no
> longer exists once a workflow is complete

it feels that caching would be the only option.

But according to the CircelCI documentation, my case doesn't fit their cache defintions:

> Use the cache to store data that makes your job faster, but, in the
> case of a cache miss or zero cache restore, the job still runs
> successfully. For example, you might cache NPM package directories
> (known as node_modules).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can totally use caching here. Make sure you [choose your key template(s)](https://circleci.com/docs/caching#using-keys-and-templates) wisely.

The caveat to keep in mind is that (unlike the job level where you can use the `requires` key), there's no *native *way to sequentially execute workflows. Although you could consider using an orb for that; for example the [`roopakv/swissknife` orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/roopakv/swissknife).

So you'll need to make sure that the job (that needs the file) in the `deploy` workflow, doesn't move to the `restore_cache` step until the `save_cache` in the other job has happened.